# Build haskell stack tests without running

Tags: haskell, command-line-arguments, haskell-stack, build-tools

I've made a very simple project with a failing test suite https://github.com/k-bx/noruntests-play

Now when I run `stack --test --no-run-tests build` I would expect it to build the project, but not run the tests. Instead, it runs the tests:

```
➜  noruntests-play git:(master) stack --test --no-run-tests build
noruntests-play-0.1.0.0: test (suite: test)

test: error
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at tests/Tests.hs:4:8 in main:Main

Test suite failure for package noruntests-play-0.1.0.0
    test:  exited with: ExitFailure 1
Logs printed to console
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put `build` option before `--test` like this:

```
$ stack build --test --no-run-tests
```

I'm not sure whether it's bug or feature. You can open issue [here](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues) if you're interested in feedback from developers. Personally for me it seems strange to pass `--test` before `build`. In some reasonable sense `--test` is subpart of `build` and subparts or options are usually specified to the right of main option.

Also there's shorter version of what you want (because `build --test` is just `test`):

```
$ stack test --no-run-tests
```

Comment: I think you're right in a way, on the other hand if that option is not recognized it would be better IMHO to not silently throw it away, but report an error or a warning. I'll make a ticket.